# a href is not working after postback in updatepanel

Tags: html, asp.net, hyperlink, webforms, updatepanel

I have a hyperlink in `updatepanel` and when I update the `updatepanel` then hyperlink is not clickable or not sending to the other page. But if I refresh the page hyperlink is working.

My hyperlink in `updatepanel`:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
      `<a href="/cart">Cart</a>` 
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Button ID="update" runat="server" OnClick="update_Click" Text="Update"></aspButton>
```

I have used button for update and button is outside of updatepanel:

```
protected void update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   updatepanel.update();
}
```

When i click on the update button than hyperlink is dead. Not sending to the destination page and seems update process is working at the same time.

I just want to learn how can I make hyperlink alive again.

**SOLUTION**:

There is nothing wrong with the code. Problem was the imported jquery library. Overriding all hyperlinks in my example. That is why i have faced with this problem. I have deleted the code. I hope it helps.

Comment: You need to create a [MCVE]. You don't have enough code here to reproduce the issue.

Comment: i just edited the code a little bit. It's a sample that i'm trying to make it work. updatepanel.Update() is working. Problem is html hyperlink is being useless after update. @mason

Comment: Your question still isn't complete. You haven't shown how update_Click gets called. And you have extra tickmarks in your code that I doubt are present in the actual code. The goal for the code in your question would be that I can take it and drop it into a brand new web app, and get the same error that you're getting.

Comment: Your code would not compile, your closing tag for your button is invalid. You still have those unneeded tickmarks in your code. I suggest you copy all the relevant code to a new web app, and determine exactly what the minimal amount of code is that will  reproduce your issue. If you can't solve it after that, *then* you'll have a valid question.

Comment: Are you perhaps modifiing the href with jquery?

Comment: @VDWWD thank you.i found jquery overrides all the hyperlinks. problem solved.